# How to encrypt user files securely on the server with PHP

Tags: encryption, php, account-security, file-encryption, file-access

## Description:

I want to create an upload center for small files (word/excel/zip documents etc) with PHP.

1. I want to protect files uploaded by user as much as possible, so if server is breached, attacker cannot read/open these files.
2. I just want to minimize the damage in case of a breach/attack.
3. If all encrypted files are breached, and cannot be decrypted it's okay
4. It's acceptable if in worst case scenario a few files are breached (unencrypted), or even files for a few users, but not all files at once etc (like I said, just trying to minimize the damage).
5. In best case scenario only the user (who uploaded files) can access his own (unencrypted) files, but it is okay if Admin can also read those.

## What I've already thought of:

1. First I thought of having a random password created for each file, storing that password in database but before storing them, those passwords are also encrypted by a master password defined by admin. But if the server is breached, attacker can also have access to both passwords and files and it only gives him a little extra effort... which seems like false sense of security.
2. Then I thought that each user, can have a secondary encryption password, stored in `$_SESSION` (before storing it in SESSION it is encrypted by a random temporary key), that `$_SESSION` password is only used to encrypt and decrypt files. But in case the user wants to change this password, we have to rewrite all older encrypted files... or store that old password on database and encrypt it with the new password to use for those old files! which makes things complicated.

Is there a better way to do this with a single server and no extra hardware?

Do any of my ideas provide the minimal (best I can) security I'm looking for?

Comment: i would have the client encrypt the file before it went over the wire. that means you don't have to store keys or do fancy encryptiony things on your server. KDF and window.crypto would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks but I think that would cause most clients to not use the service at all, not really beginner-friendly and user-friendly.

Comment: it would/could be completely transparent to the end user, especially if you persisted the user-supplied password correctly.

Comment: @dandavis Oh, I initially thought they have to enter the password for every single file they upload, and also for every single file they download. I've never heard of a way to persist the main password securely and safely on the client side. Thanks, I will try to do some research on that now, but if you have a link to a good online article/book, please kindly share it with me.

Comment: @J.Doe Persisting the password on the client isn't implied by the threat model that server-side encryption would require. If you want to protect client data in the case that your server gets breached, why would it matter if the users have their own passwords cached or not?

Comment: @forest So basically, you're saying I can store user's RAW password even as a cookie on user browser, and I'm still doing this the right way? Yes, I want to "protect client data in the case that your server gets breached" but I also want to follow security guidelines, shouldn't I at least derive an encryption key from the password and then store that one?

Comment: @J.Doe Yeah you don't need to store the plaintext password anywhere (hashing is fine). What I mean is just that you don't need to implement any kind of client-side encryption.